# Get the id from the element it belongs to, PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to get the id from the element that the subtitle file belong to, how do i combine a foreach $_POST and foreach $_FILES so that i can get the id ?

[image]

Here is my php code:

```
foreach ($_POST['episodes'] as $episodes => $value ) {
$episode_title = $value['episode_title'];
$sql_episode = "INSERT INTO episode VALUES ('', '$episode_title', 'description', '1')";
    if ($db->query($sql_episode) === TRUE) {

        $inserted_id_episodes = $db->insert_id;

        if (isset($value['subtitle'])) {
            foreach ($value['subtitle'] as $subtitle) {
              $language = $subtitle['language'];
              $sql_subtitle = "INSERT INTO added_subtitle VALUES ('', '$language', 'path', '$inserted_id_episodes')";
                if ($db->query($sql_subtitle) === TRUE) {
                    $inserted_id_subtitle = $db->insert_id; //this is the id I want to get.

                    if(!empty($_FILES['subtitlePath'])){
                        foreach($_FILES['subtitlePath']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
                            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['subtitlePath']['name'][$key];
                            $file_size = $_FILES['subtitlePath']['size'][$key];
                            $file_tmp = $_FILES['subtitlePath']['tmp_name'][$key];
                            $file_type = $_FILES['subtitlePath']['type'][$key];
                            $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["subtitlePath"]["name"][$key]);
                            $target_dir = "../images/covers/";
                            $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
                            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_file);
                            $sql_subtitlePath = "UPDATE added_subtitle SET  subtitle_path = '$target_file' WHERE ID = '$inserted_id_subtitle'"; // I wan't to update the table with that inserted id 
                            $result = $db->query($sql_subtitlePath);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form  action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="episodes[0][episode_title]" value="">

<input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle][0][language]" value="">
<input type="file" name="subtitlePath[3]" value="">

<input type="text" name="episodes[0][subtitle][1][language]" value="">
<input type="file" name="subtitlePath[3]" value="">

<input type="text" name="episodes[1][episode_title]" value="">

<input type="text" name="episodes[1][subtitle][0][language]" value="">
<input type="file" name="subtitlePath[3]" value="">


</form>
```

I hope that someone is able to help me doing this, So how to combine the foreach $_POST and foreach $_FILES. Thanks!

Comment: Your multiple `subtitlePath[3]` fields overwrite each other.

Comment: sorry it is a mistake, it is getting a new number when i add it, using javascript, to add them and give the numbers.